# Tableau Export PDF with custom template

Tags: tableau-api

I have a viz showing on our site and the sales people may have customized it by running filters on it. This customized report we want to export as a pdf. Can i customize this some how to use a specific header and text as well?

Here are some things that i would like to include

1. I want to put a custom header/image
2. Some text to show contact us/sales rep info and some descriptive text
3. The viz as it is displaying with filter applied
4. Some text underneath the viz

FYI: this viz is showing on our site. I am not referring to Tableau server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, with Tableau Server there is a tool called tabcmd that you can use to create a PDF of the viz on Server (see http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-tabcmd).

Once you have created the PDF you would need to run a second job with something like Coherent's PDF Command Line Tools (http://www.coherentpdf.com/usage-examples.html) to mark up the PDF with the content you want to add.